# Ошибка при любом DML-запросе к таблице - ORA-00942 Table or View Does Not Exists

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, oracle11g

Жила-была таблица Bar в схеме Foo. Давно жила в производственной базе, было у неё не много строк, но весьма много внешних ключей и иных упоминаний. Запросы на чтение к таблице выполнялись каждую минуту, а когда и секунду. DML-запросы случались не часто, около 10-100 в год. Но никогда проблем с ними не было.

И тут в один обыкновенный рабочий день, перестали проходить DML запросы. На любой DML ошибка

> ora-00942 Table or View Does Not Exists

При этом запросы на чтение прекрасно проходят. Что же это за напасть с таблицей? Как узнать? Как победить?

---

#### Дополнения.

1. Запросы не работают как от имени Foo, так и от других пользователей.
2. Изменения регистра имени таблицы и полей в строке запроса не помогают.
3. `select * from all_objects where object_name like '%BAR%'` возвращает

   > `OWNER | OBJECT_NAME`
   >
   > `-------------------`
   >
   > `FOO   | BAR`
4. `select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'BAR'` Поля тоже все в верхнем регистре, HEX чистый.
5. Привожу результаты из sqlplus

.

```
SQL> select BARID from BAR where BARID = 'XYZ';

BARID
------------------
XYZ

SQL> update BAR set BAR_NAME = 'ABC' WHERE BARID = 'XYZ';
update BAR set BAR_NAME = 'ABC' WHERE BARID = 'XYZ'
       *
ошибка в строке 1:
ORA-00942: таблица или представление пользователя не существует


SQL>
```

6. DDL-запрос на добавление нового столбца и его удаление проходит без ошибок.
7. Перезагрузка инстанса не помогла

Comment: Самые частые причины подобной неприятности, если верить оракловому форуму - косяки с регистром имени таблицы/поля.

Comment: И в этот обыкновенный рабочий день надо пойти и спросить у DBA, что они сделали такого необыкновенного.

Comment: @0xdb, увы не получится по двум причинам: 1) ДБА нет в принципе 2) никто ничего такого не делал.

Comment: @Akina, я не очень понял вас, т.к. база всегда была регистронезависимой для идентификаторов. Но я, на всякий случай, перепробовал написать запрос в самых разнообразных регистрах и ничего не получилось

Comment: *база всегда была регистронезависимой для идентификаторов* Некоторые товарищи любят заквотить имена при создании - а они при этом получаются как раз регистрозависимыми вроде бы как... во всяком случае, словить "неизвестный токен" становится легче лёгкого... *перепробовал написать запрос в самых разнообразных регистрах* Посмотрите в системной таблице точное имя именно как оно там написано. На всякий случай...

Comment: @Akina, `select * from all_objects where object_name like '%BAR%'` ? там верхний регистр, перепроверил HEX на предмет лишних символов

Comment: Попробуйте в sqlplus выполнить select и update (или вставку) и покажите результат, то есть всего четыре строчки.

Comment: @0xdb, добавил из sqlplus

Comment: То есть, вы создали новую схему FOO, создали в ней таблицу BAR, и ошибка воспроизводится. Правильно я понял?

Comment: Пробовали явно указать имя схемы в UPDATE или через `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = FOO`?

Comment: @0xdb Нет, конечно, ошибка с одной конкретной таблицей. Вы хотите увидеть настоящее название?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, Явно пробовал, `ALTER SESSION` ещё нет. Я авторизовался под владельцем схемы. (и не под владельцем тоже).

Comment: _хотите увидеть настоящее название_ - нет конечно, просто опасаюсь, что пока вы редактируете, то можете пару деталей затереть. Посмотрите триггера на таблице, если они есть, то что они делают.

Comment: @0xdb, смотрел, нет триггеров на таблице. Может бывают какие глобальные триггеры? Может есть защита по записи таблицы? Я (и не только я) столько раз уже писал эти запросы вручную и автоматом через утилиты (Oracle SQL Developer, Pl\Sql Developer, даже MS ACCESS через ODBC-драйвер), что опечатки исключены. Вообще название таблицы содержит цифры, если это имеет какое-то значение. аля `B321AR`

Comment: Нет, "глобальных" триггеров я не знаю. Включайте трассировку, смотрите логи.  _никто ничего такого не делал_ - если вчера работало, а сегодня нет, то это значит, что в этот промежуток времени что-то изменилось. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: И чем закончились поиски, виновника нашли?

Comment: @0xdb, пока ничем. Вкорячили костыль со вью исправляющей данные в самом критическом месте. Решили перезагружать инстанс, но пока не решили когда.

Comment: @0xdb, нашли...

Comment: @4per Как и говорил, кто-то что-то сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было так.
Зачем-то на таблицу `Foo.Bar` был заведён *Materialized Views Log*. Это было давным давно. А вот незадолго до появлении проблемы некто переименовал таблицу `Foo.M$LOG_Bar` в `Foo.DeleteMe_M$LOG_Bar`.

Т.е. при dml-запросах

> ora-00942 Table or View Does Not Exists

означало, что нет таблицы с логом.

Обратное переименование, однако не помогло. Но так как этот лог вовсе не нужен был, помогло его удаление. Теперь DML работают.

Answer (score 3):

Причина указана в [ответе ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135117). Ошибка действительно воспроизводится в версии 11.2:

```sql
11g> create table bar as select 1 id, 'memo 1' memo from dual;

Table created.

11g> create materialized view log on bar with rowid;

Materialized view log created.

11g> alter table mlog$_bar rename to del_mlog$_bar;

Table altered.

11g> update bar set memo='**memo' where id=1;
update bar set memo='**memo' where id=1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

В последующих версиях эта ошибка была исправлена, больше невозможно переместить или удалить таблицу с логами материализованого представления:

```sql
19c> alter table mlog$_bar rename to del_mlog$_bar;
alter table mlog$_bar rename to del_mlog$_bar
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32433: cannot rename a materialized view log
```

---

Так как в дереве зависимостей логи материализованого представления отсутствуют, то для быстрой локализации ошибки надо было: провести поиск всех объектов со схожим именем, ну или просто помнить, что на таблице может существовать MV Log:

```sql
11g> select object_name, object_type from obj where object_name like '%BAR%';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
DEL_MLOG$_BAR                  TABLE
BAR                            TABLE

11g> select master, log_table from user_mview_logs;

MASTER                         LOG_TABLE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
BAR                            MLOG$_BAR
```